# jQuery vs GQuery Benchmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, benchmarking, gquery

I remember stumbling upon a benchmark comparing jQuery vs GQuery (run time selectors) vs GQuery (compile time selectors).
Once the site was loaded one could click "Start" and the benchmark (mostly CSS selectors) would run for all three versions and present the results (overall time spent) after finishing.
Unfortunately, I cannot find it anymore.
I do **not** refer to the "horse race" benchmark in Ray Cromwell's excellent video.

Does anyone know this benchmark and provide me with the link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is the one you were after: http://letusdemo.appspot.com/

The versions there are way out of date.

Comment: ...then why would you mention it?

Comment: Because it's better then nothing. I looked at that page, and found it intriguing, despite the versions being out of date.

Comment: This is the site I was looking for, thank you!
Does anyone know about similar, but more recent benchmarks?

Comment: @Bears will not eat me - It is better than nothing just as helpful as your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link:
http://gwtquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/gwtquery.samples.GwtQueryBench/GwtQueryBench.html?ask=false

You have also a comparative of different browsers running the benchmark here:
http://manolocarrasco.blogspot.com/2011/01/gwtquery-css-selectors-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

This one is newer http://www.cinsoft.net/slickspeed.html or just query slickspeed